# Android TV Ads don't play properly on Amazon Fire TV

Tags: android, ads, android-tv, amazon-fire-tv

I'm implementing an Android TV app that I also want to run on Amazon Fire. On a Nexus Android TV it works fine. However, when the ads play on Amazon Fire TV, the audio plays normally, but the video of the ad freezes and I get a lot of the frames dropped. On the Debug console I get the following: (I trimmed it down because the

```
I/MediaCodecLogger: com.example.myapp.SW.video.vp8 Dropping frame
```

happened a lot!)

```
D/EventLogger: state [18.53, false, R]
I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 11325(866KB) AllocSpace objects, 8(6MB) LOS objects, 16% free, 80MB/96MB, paused 6.062ms total 83.822ms
D/CRLSetManager: getInstance binder: android.os.BinderProxy@522337f
D/CRLSetManager: getInstance binder: android.os.BinderProxy@522337f
W/IMASDK: Invalid internal message, ignoring. Please make sure the Google IMA SDK library is up to date. Message: gmsg://afma.google.com/    activityMonitor?type=getPageSignals&sid=b8e09269-21cd-42a3-9895-9438df4bd19c&dt=1530233910925
I/ExoPlayerImpl: Init ExoPlayerLib/1.5.16
D/CRLSetManager: getInstance binder: android.os.BinderProxy@522337f
D/CRLSetManager: getInstance binder: android.os.BinderProxy@522337f
I/OMXClient: MuxOMX ctor
I/MediaCodec: [OMX.google.vp8.decoder] setting surface generation to 6702082
I/MediaCodecLogger: [ASAP] SW.video.vp8 P2 + 97280
D/MediaCodecLogger: Got a Service. Calling PID = 6545
E/ACodec: [OMX.google.vp8.decoder] storeMetaDataInBuffers failed w/ err -1010
I/MediaCodecLogger: [ASAP] SW.video.vp8 P2 - 97288
I/MediaCodecLogger: [ASAP] SW.video.vp8 P3 + 97289
I/MediaCodecLogger: [ASAP] SW.video.vp8 P3 - 97297
I/OMXClient: MuxOMX ctor
I/MediaCodecLogger: [ASAP] SW.audio.vorbis P2 + 97309
D/MediaCodecLogger: Got a Service. Calling PID = 6545
I/MediaCodecLogger: [ASAP] SW.audio.vorbis P2 - 97312
I/MediaCodecLogger: [ASAP] SW.audio.vorbis P3 + 97312
I/MediaCodecLogger: [ASAP] SW.audio.vorbis P3 - 97316
I/MediaCodecLogger: [ASAP] SW.audio.vorbis Got First Input Frame 97318
I/MediaCodecLogger: [ASAP] SW.video.vp8 Got First Input Frame 97502
D/AudioTrack: min buf count is limited to 2 times HAL buf
I/MediaCodecLogger: updatePTSTime [SW.audio.vorbis] First PTS after Flush or reset = 3000
                    [ASAP] SW.audio.vorbis Got First Frame Ready 97522
D/AmazonAudioTrackCallback: No AudioTrackFlags provided.  Using internal defaults.
D/android.media.AudioTrack: AUDIOINFO: audio_input: format: 2 sample_rate: 44100 channels: 2 AudioAttributes: AudioAttributes: usage=1 content=2 flags=0x0 tags= bundle=null
D/AudioTrack: min buf count is limited to 2 times HAL buf
D/AudioTrack: Client defaulted notificationFrames to 3675 for frameCount 11025
D/MediaCodec: [OMX.google.vp8.decoder] setting dataspace on output surface to #104
I/MediaCodecLogger: updatePTSTime [SW.video.vp8] First PTS after Flush or reset = 0
                    [ASAP] SW.video.vp8 Got First Frame Ready 97651
D/SoftwareRenderer: setting dataspace on output surface to #104
I/MediaCodecLogger: [ASAP] SW.video.vp8 Got First Frame Render 97685
                    App uses Timestamps for AVSync
I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 49466(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 1(20KB) LOS objects, 3% free, 93MB/96MB, paused 1.797ms total 105.188ms
I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 13227(675KB) AllocSpace objects, 1(504KB) LOS objects, 14% free, 96MB/112MB, paused 2.500ms total 128.301ms
I/MediaCodecLogger: com.example.myapp.SW.audio.vorbis.bitrateInKbps = 149
I/MediaCodecLogger: com.example.myapp.SW.video.vp8.bitrateInKbps = 2951
I/MediaCodecLogger: com.example.myapp.SW.video.vp8 Resolution change from 0x0 to 1920x1080 took = 4622
I/MediaCodecLogger: com.example.myapp.SW.video.vp8 Dropping frame
I/MediaCodecLogger: com.example.myapp.SW.audio.vorbis.bitrateInKbps = 163
I/MediaCodecLogger: com.example.myapp.SW.video.vp8 Dropping frame
I/MediaCodecLogger: com.example.myapp.SW.video.vp8.bitrateInKbps = 6819
I/MediaCodecLogger: com.example.myapp.SW.video.vp8 Dropping frame
I/MediaCodecLogger: com.example.myapp.SW.audio.vorbis.bitrateInKbps = 168
I/MediaCodecLogger: com.example.myapp.SW.video.vp8 Dropping frame
I/MediaCodecLogger: com.example.myapp.SW.video.vp8.bitrateInKbps = 6013
I/MediaCodecLogger: com.example.myapp.SW.video.vp8 Dropping frame
I/MediaCodecLogger: com.example.myapp.SW.audio.vorbis.bitrateInKbps = 157
I/MediaCodecLogger: com.example.myapp.SW.video.vp8 Dropping frame
I/MediaCodecLogger: com.example.myapp.SW.video.vp8.bitrateInKbps = 8363
I/MediaCodecLogger: com.example.myapp.SW.video.vp8 Dropping frame
I/MediaCodecLogger: W.mcfd520.com.example.myapp.SW.video.vp8 Dropping frame
I/MediaCodecLogger: com.example.myapp.SW.audio.vorbis.bitrateInKbps = 156
I/MediaCodecLogger: W.mcfd520.com.example.myapp.SW.video.vp8 Dropping frame
I/MediaCodecLogger: W.mcfd520.com.example.myapp.SW.video.vp8.bitrateInKbps = 4541
I/MediaCodecLogger: W.mcfd520.com.example.myapp.SW.video.vp8 Dropping frame
I/MediaCodecLogger: W.mcfd520.com.example.myapp.SW.video.vp8.bitrateInKbps = 6255
I/MediaCodecLogger: updatePTSTime Possible seek found!
I/MediaCodecLogger: MC Stop Time(start: 128121, stop:128130 :9 <profileMCStopEnd 769>
                    com.example.myapp.SW.video.vp8.TotalVideoPlaybackTimeMs = 29930
                    com.example.myapp.SW.video.vp8.videoResolution.FHD = 29930
I/MediaCodecLogger: com.example.myapp.SW.video.vp8.StreamAvgFramerate = 26.696
                    com.example.myapp.SW.video.vp8.OneConsecutiveFramesDropped = 3
                    com.example.myapp.SW.video.vp8.TwoConsecutiveFramesDropped = 9
                    com.example.myapp.SW.video.vp8.TenConsecutiveFramesDropped = 64
                    com.example.myapp.SW.video.vp8.TotalFramesDropped = 661
                    com.example.myapp.SW.video.vp8.MaxConsecutiveFramesDropped = 520
                    com.example.myapp.SW.video.vp8.ASAP-P5Ms = 183
                    com.example.myapp.SW.video.vp8.ASAP-P2Ms = 8
                    com.example.myapp.SW.video.vp8.ASAP-P3Ms = 8
                    com.example.myapp.SW.video.vp8.FirstFrameReadyMs = 149
                    com.example.myapp.SW.video.vp8.StreamAvgBitrateInKbps = 5823
I/MediaCodecLogger: com.example.myapp.SW.video.vp8.ASAP-P2Ms = 0
I/MediaCodecLogger: com.example.myapp.SW.video.vp8.ASAP-P3Ms = 0
                    com.example.myapp.SW.video.vp8.FirstFrameReadyMs = 0
I/MediaCodecLogger: com.example.myapp.SW.audio.vorbis.TotalAudioPlaybackTimeMs = 29981
                    com.example.myapp.SW.audio.vorbis.StreamAvgBitrateInKbps = 158
```

I'm using these as part of my dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.google.ads.interactivemedia.v3:interactivemedia:3.8.2"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.7.1"
}
```

Is there a particular SDK to play DFP ads on Amazon Fire?

Comment: I noticed that the errors are VP8 related and checking the Amazon Developer docs: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/fire-tv/device-specifications.html?v=ftvgen3 shows that VP8 isn't supported (you didn't mention which device you are testing on). If possible deliver ads with a supported codec.

Comment: Testing on an Amazon Fire TV 3rd Generation with 4K and Alexa Voice Remote

Comment: Yeah, your link clearly states that vp8 is not supported on 3rd Gen, I'll have to change my ads